# Metric on a set

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

Can someone provide a hint for solving the following.

Show that $d:(R^{\infty})^2\to R_+$ is a metric.
$$d(x, y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{(x_i-y_i)^2}}$$

I need a hint for showing that $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality

Comment: This $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is not a good notation. It should be $d:\ell^2(\mathbb{R})\times\ell^2(\mathbb{R})\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$. Where $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of [all sequences which are square-summable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_countably_infinite_dimensions).This is a normed vector space (even a Hilbert space). And what you want is the triagular inequality for its norm. That's called [Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) in a general $L^p$ space. It can be deduced from Hölder (so Cauchy-Schwarz in the case $p=2$).

Comment: @julien: In a comment to one of the answers, I think the OP stated that they want $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ in the "standard" sense of "all but finitely many coordinates are zero".

Comment: @robjohn I can't see such a comment. Anyway, this really is about $\ell^2$. And I think $\mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ is more standard notation for finitely supported sequences, no?

Comment: @julien: sorry, I was thinking of [Hagen von Eitzen's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/432939) (which might better be a comment). However, in the definition of an infinite dimensional vector space (without adding a Banach space structure), any element of the vector space can be written as a linear combination of a finite set of basis elements. That is, all but finitely many components are $0$. This alleviates concerns about convergence (which are usually relegated to Banach spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{Hint:}$ Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I asked for a hint not a proof.

Comment: Ok, I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I assume that your $\mathbb R^\infty$ is the set of all sequences of real numbers such that at most *finitely* many entries are nonzero.

Comment: Yes, if we want the result to be finite.

Comment: So, given $x,y,z$ you can find a finite $N$ such that $x,y,z\in\ldots$.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a hint how to prove the triangle inequality.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes, that's what I need. How do I use Hagen's hint?

Comment: @saadtaame I was assuming that you'd already know that the corresponding expresssion (Euklidean distance) is a metric on $\mathbb R^N$. So my ral hint was the italicization of the word "finitely".